# Display none ajuda a resolver lentidão em um site onepage?

Tags: html, css

O site é onepage e está separado pelos respectivos article e section.

Quando se faz scroll, os elementos que não fazem falta (article) continuam em palco porém fora dos limites do browser.

Devido a acumulação de elementos, o site tem tendência a fica mais lento.

Quando um article sair dos limites de visualização da tela, ou seja, não ser mais visível para o utilizador, aplicar um display none irá fazer diferença?

Ou uma vez renderizado, somente removendo o elemento do HTML para obter uma melhor performance, pelo menos ao fazer scroll.

Comment: Em elementos fora do view-port estou usando a técnica, mas criei uma caixa com altura fixa para que não afete os elementos fora, parece que ajuda naqueles infinity-scroll, mas não posso afirmar. Até aonde pesquisei parece que `visibilty: hidden` pode uma razoável vantagem, mas todos links que encontrei são um tanto quanto teoricos.

Answer (score 0):

Felipe,

Imagine uma pintura.
Você tem um fundo branco e começar a desenhar uma maçã com um monte de detalhes durante uma hora e depois você cobre completamente com outra camada de tinta branca. Essa é a visibilidade.

`display: none` é como se não tivesse desenhado desde o início. É claro que é mais rápido na primeira carga.

Há desvantagens quando você estiver usando `display: none` todavia: quando você está alternando de volta para o bloco (ou inline, etc) você terá que começar a desenhar a pintura, mas usando a visibilidade que o navegador é apenas arranhando a última demão de tinta e ele está de volta. Assim, a visibilidade é mais rápida neste caso.

Mas lembre-se uma coisa quando você estiver usando visibility: hidden o elemento mantém a sua posição no fluxo de modo que os elementos em torno dele não vai ceder.

Se você quer uma explicação técnica verifique a palestra de [David Baron](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a2_6bGNZ7bA#t=43m08s).

uma forma de otimizar o seu site é utilizar o [PageSpeed Tools da Google](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/?hl=pt) ele te mostra como otimizar a sua página para mobile/desktop passando tudo o que esta incorreto e sugerindo possíveis melhorias.

achei aqui [Lots of DOM. Hidden vs display none](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4718342/lots-of-dom-hidden-vs-display-none)

Comment: Amigo a resposta é boa, mas a questão está longe de ser isto, a questão do autor é sobre a renderização que ocorre no tempo de execução do lado do cliente e não com questão de requisição HTTP.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento achei um conteúdo mais focado nisso estou fazendo a tradução para se encaixar

Comment: Eu vi o link, recomendo que traduza ele e poste no corpo da sua resposta, links podem ser uteis, mas podem quebrar no futuro e a resposta ficaria sem sentido.

Answer (score 0):

Em suma, não. Aplicar um `display: none` *depois* que o elemento já foi criado e renderizado na tela não deve afetar drasticamente a sua performance. Você estará basicamente sumindo com algo que já foi criado, e portanto já lhe exigiu tempo de processamento. Esses elementos estarão carregados no DOM, tanto que você pode interagir com eles via javascript sem maiores problemas.

Por outro lado, se, inicialmente, o elemento tiver a dita propriedade, todos os elementos *dentro dele* terão o seu render impedido, o que, dependendo de como a sua página está arquitetada, pode sim lhe trazer alguns benefícios.

Se você procura uma solução *on demand* (que não acho que seja o caso, visto o escopo da sua pergunta), na qual o usuário só recebe o conteúdo quando necessário, você pode usar AJAX, que é feito de maneira bem simples usando jQuery.